# Alignment of two components for an input field (Label + Field)

Tags: html, css

This is my current input field styling however for some reason which I am unable to see, they are not aligning properly next to each other.

Code:

```
<div class="labelInputField">Confirm Password</div><input type="text" class="inputField">

.labelInputField {
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        padding: 8px;
        width: 150px;
        color: white;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
        border: 2px solid #000;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .inputField {
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        padding: 8px;
        width: 180px;
        color: white;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        border: 2px solid #000;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0Lsake9j/

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `margin-top:15px` and add `line-height:30px;` in `.labelInputField` style. That will make your div and input alignment proper.

```css
    .labelInputField {
      border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
      padding: 8px;
      width: 150px;
      color: white;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
      border: 2px solid #000;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 30px;
        line-height:30px;
      font-size: 16px;
     }
     .inputField {
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
      padding: 8px;
      width: 180px;
      color: white;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      border: 2px solid #000;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 30px;
      font-size: 16px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="labelInputField">Confirm Password</div><input type="text" class="inputField">
```

You can also test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/p5ub06gm/)

Comment: Still not inline for me and neither is it on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

1. Offload layout responsibility to a container and/or additional layers of markup.
2. Remove margin-top on the div
3. Use a `<label for="[YOUR_INPUT_ID]"></label>` and ensure your input has `id="[YOUR_INPUT_ID]"`.
4. Add `type="password"` on your input, unless you have a specific reason not to.
5. Remove existing layouts styles from selectors that are styling the input and label (i.e. `inline-block` in this case.).
6. Apply your layout styling with an object that's sole purpose is to handle layout of your elements

```css
.iHandleLayout {
    display: flex;
  /* rest of your layout styling etc.   */
}

.labelInputField {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 150px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border: 2px solid #000;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .inputField {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 180px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border: 2px solid #000;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="iHandleLayout">
  <label class="labelInputField" for="password">Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="inputField" id="password">
</div>
```

In the end, there are many ways to control the layout (display: inline-block, flex, table, etc), but the main principle is the separation of concerns with your styling and the markup structure as part of that separation.